# javafx - how to properly use the high contrast themes?

Tags: java, javafx, accessibility

I have noticed on scenebuilder that a modena high contrast theme exists.

How do I properly use it? I mean in a cross platform or implementation way.

I noticed that a yellowOnBlack.css and whiteOnBlack.css exists inside de jfxrt.jar on the Oracle implementation at jfxrt.jar\com\sun\javafx\scene\control\skin\modena.

How do I apply it without copying de CSS or referencing the path of a specific implementation?

Thank you.

Comment: Not too sure how to change to it programmatically without specifying the url using `Application.setUserAgentStylesheet()` since it's not a constant in the `Application` class like `STYLESHEET_CASPIAN` and `STYLESHEET_MODENA`. However, the user can manually change to a high contrast theme using `Alt + Left Shift + Print Screen' on Windows so perhaps this event could be created and fired, but I'm not sure if that'd work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8120025) you can set this with a command line option `-Dcom.sun.javafx.highContrastTheme`. The valid values are `yellowOnBlack`, `whiteOnBlack`, or `blackOnWhite`.

I.e. you should be able to run your application with, for example

```
java -Dcom.sun.javafx.highContrastTheme=yellowOnBlack com.example.MyApp
```

I haven't tested this, but it may be possible to set this programmatically via `System.setProperty(...)`, though you probably have to make sure the property is set early enough in the life cycle of the application (maybe even before the application class is loaded).

Comment: It works. I think javafx nees a better way to do this, but currently it's the only solution that works (as it seems).